# Databinding with Django channels in custom command

Tags: python, django, data-binding, websocket, django-channels

I start work with Django channels. I need bind data of my model Device. I do it. When I change Device object in admin interface I get message about changing on client (web browser) but I also run simple WebsocketServer by means of custom django management command. And when Device-object has been changed in custom command process I don't receive any message on client. How I can fix it?

devices/models.py

```
OFFLINE = 0
ONLINE = 1
REGISTRATION = 2
REMOVED = 3
ERROR = 4


STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (OFFLINE, _("Offline")),
    (ONLINE, _("Online")),
    (REGISTRATION, _("Registration")),
    (REMOVED, _("Removed")),
    (ERROR, _("Error")),
)


class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128,
                            null=True, blank=True, default=None, verbose_name=_("Name"))
    created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_("Creation date time"), editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_("Last change date time"), blank=True)

    removed = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_("Device has been removed"), default=False)
    remove_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_("Date of Device removing"),
                                       null=True, blank=True,
                                       default=None)

    joined = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_("Registration status"), default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_("Registration date time"), blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    owner = models.ForeignKey("accounts.User",
                              null=True, blank=True, default=None,
                              verbose_name=_("Who registered"), on_delete=models.SET(None))

    status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, blank=True, default=REGISTRATION, verbose_name=_("Status"))
    frozen = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_("Device is frozen"))
```

devices/databinding.py

```
from channels.binding.websockets import WebsocketBinding

from .models import Device


class DeviceBinding(WebsocketBinding):

    model = Device
    stream = "device"
    fields = ['status', 'joined', 'frozen']

    @classmethod
    def group_names(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return ["binding.devices"]

    def has_permission(self, user, action, pk):
        return True  # FIXME: check permission for user
```

project/routing.py

```
from channels import route_class, route
from devices.consumers import Demultiplexer
from devices.databinding import DeviceBinding

channel_routing = [
    route_class(Demultiplexer, path='^/stream/?$'),
    route("binding.device", DeviceBinding.consumer),
]
```

devices/consumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websockets import WebsocketDemultiplexer


class Demultiplexer(WebsocketDemultiplexer):

    mapping = {
        "device": "binding.device",
    }

    def connection_groups(self):
        return ["binding.devices"]
```

My simple custom command where I run custom autobahn WebSockerServer.

project/management/commands/runcustomcommand.py

```
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from project.websocketserver.autobahn_server import WebSocketServer

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Run WebSocket Server"

    # A command must define handle()
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        wss = WebSocketServer()
        wss.start()
```

project/websocketserver/autobahn_server.py

class WebSocketServer(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    import sys

    from twisted.python import log

    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

    self.factory = WebSocketServerFactory(
            "ws://{host}:{port}".format(
                    host=settings.WSS_HOST, port=settings.WSS_PORT),
            # debug=False
    )
    self.factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol
    self.factory.setProtocolOptions(
            autoPingInterval=settings.WSS_AUTO_PING_INTERVAL,
            autoPingTimeout=settings.WSS_AUTO_PING_TIMEOUT
    )

def start(self):
    from twisted.internet import reactor

    try:
        logger.info("\tSTART SERVER")
        reactor.listenTCP(settings.WSS_PORT, self.factory)
        reactor.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        self.stop()

def stop(self):
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    reactor.stop()
    logger.info("\tSTOP SERVER")
```

connetion on client (js code):

```
var ws_path = "ws://127.0.0.1:8001/stream/";
console.log("Connecting to " + ws_path);
var webSocket = new WebSocket(ws_path);

webSocket.onopen = function() {
alert("Connected!.");
};

webSocket.onmessage = function(message) {
var data = JSON.parse(message.data);
alert(data);
};

webSocket.onerror = function(error) {
alert("Error: " + error.message);
};
```

I run:

```
redis-server
daphne project.asgi:channel_layer --port 8001
python manage.py runworker -v2
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000  -v2

python manage.py runcustomcommand
```

**UPDATE**

I accidentally discovered that if add this code in begin of my management command, subsequent changes to the objects come to the client:

```
from channels import Channel
Channel("binding.devices").send({})
```

It's like some kind of initialization. But it is strange.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same thing, though I cannot say for certain it may be that your `DeviceBinding.group_names` and `Demultiplexer.connection_groups` methods are not returning lists. Make sure they have the trailing commas `["binding.device", ]` and `["binding.devices", ]`. Apart from that the only difference I can see is that I used a different group name as I have multiple models to bind and for simplicity used one group.

Hope that helps, 
Stu